# Populating a database externally with information on a client page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, greasemonkey

I am looking to build a personal project in which i am on a website and want to pull text from it to populate my database.

I think i need to have JavaScript running as an extension/greasemonkey and then populate an ASP.NET form (not visible to the user) with the data before submitting the invisible form to populate my database

What i am asking really is A: is this possible, and if so could somebody provide me with some information or sources so that i can get a working idea?

Comment: what are you trying to archive here ?

Comment: Just short data from a game i play so that i can archive my actions on it by recording data from the page i visit

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with greasemonkey. You can create a form in javascript, set the action to your asp.net page that will save the data. Then you populate the form fields with data, and call form.submit method.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it on server side. You can use DOM parsers such as [SharpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/) or [Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to read load and lead HTML document and populate your database.

Comment: Thanks ill check those out too. Though i would prefer this to be primarily client side